# Error when changing the log file for appending logs in a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I face this error when I change the file where I write logs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="FileAppender" fileName="logs/api.log" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="myPackage" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

this is the method that changes the file where logs are added

```
   public static void updateLogger(String fileName, String appenderName, String packageName) {
        LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        Configuration configuration = context.getConfiguration();
        Layout<? extends Serializable> oldLayout = configuration.getAppender(appenderName).getLayout();

        // Delete old appender/logger
        configuration.getAppender(appenderName).stop();
        configuration.removeLogger(packageName);

        // Create new appender/logger
        LoggerConfig loggerConfig = new LoggerConfig(packageName, Level.ALL, false);
        FileAppender appender = FileAppender.newBuilder()
                .withFileName(fileName)
                .withAppend(true)
                .setName(appenderName)
                .setLayout(oldLayout)
                .build();
        appender.start();

        loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, Level.ALL, null);
        configuration.addLogger(packageName, loggerConfig);
        context.updateLoggers();
    }
```

Here where I call the method

`FileUtils.updateLogger("logs/logs/log" + ".txt", "FileAppender", "mypackage");`

Error when changing log file in Spring Boot - Logs are successfully written, but an error occurs

```
2023-08-09 15:52:23,418 MessageBroker-8 ERROR Attempted to append to non-started appender FileAppender
2023-08-09 15:52:23,422 MessageBroker-8 ERROR Unable to write to stream logs/api.log for appender FileAppender org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error writing to stream logs/api.log
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.writeToDestination(OutputStreamManager.java:252)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager.writeToDestination(FileManager.java:277)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.flushBuffer(OutputStreamManager.java:283)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.flush(OutputStreamManager.java:294)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.directEncodeEvent(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:217)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.tryAppend(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:208)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:199)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:616)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:552)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:82)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2205)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2142)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2022)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1875)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.log(LogAdapter.java:266)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.info(LogAdapter.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats.lambda$initLoggingTask$0(WebSocketMessageBrokerStats.java:128)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset$$$capture(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.writeToDestination(OutputStreamManager.java:250)
    ... 33 more
```

I'm looking to gain insights into the reason behind the occurrence of this error and seeking guidance on potential solutions. The scenario involves dynamically changing the log file in my Spring Boot application. Although the logs are being successfully written to the new file, an error message keeps appearing, also I want logs to be appending to the console too. I'd greatly appreciate any assistance in understanding why this error is happening and how to go about resolving it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The immediate reason you receive the status logger error is that you remove you appender from the "myPackage" logger config, but you don't remove it from the root logger config.

If you want to remove an appender from **all** the logger configurations and stop it, run:

```java
// Removes from all logger configuration and stops the appender
configuration.removeAppender(appenderName);
// Now we can also remove the logger configuration
configuration.removeLogger(packageName);
```

If you want to remove the appender from **just** one specific logger configuration you need to:

1. Remove the appender from the logger configuration (`LoggerConfig#removeAppender`),
2. Iterate over `Configuration#getLoggers` to see if no other logger config uses it,
3. Stop the appender if it is no longer being used.